# Grant permissions for everyone in CakePHP via CLI

Tags: php, cakephp, permissions, command-line-interface, acl

I have a CakePHP application with ACL. I am familiar with the basics of adding acos and adding  granting permissions for that aco for a specific. But I am not sure how to grant access to everyone who accesses that ago not just a group. Say I want to grant permission so everybody can see /app/contact/form.
This would be similar to the way the root index is currently working. Oh and this would be done in CLI.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cookbook is your friend http://book.cakephp.org/view/1656/allowedActions you just set this on the controller you need to be allowed.

Or you can set them in before filter http://book.cakephp.org/view/1550/Setting-up-permissions